# How to work with the latest github project version, rather than with the one I already made changes to?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2019

I have done a push of changes to github, which saved a certain point I was on in my work. I'm the only user on this github project. I then went ahead and tried to add another feature, and never pushed it so the changes I made are not on the remote server. I need to have the version from the remote server as something went wrong and I can't solve it, I don't need the changes I made. How do I work with the version that is currently on github? I tried to do a pull and it says: 'Respository is already up to date. No changes to pull' but my main file still has the changes I made, even though those changes haven't been uploaded to github.

I looked at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/gitquickstart?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio

but yeah doing a pull doesn't actually make my main.cpp go back to the version on github as soon as I pull... I don't understand why. I am working in Visual Studio 2019's team explorer. I am not knowledgeable about anything than git push to be honest.

Comment: It will depend on the state of your current workspace (HEAD). After pushing to github and  worked on your local repository again have your commited work ? If not you can either do a" git checkout ." to reset your HEAD to your previous commited work. Or do a "git stash" to save your current work in the stash (if you need it later). If you comited your work but not pushed it you can go for a "git reset COMIT-SHA" where COMIT-SHA is the commit identifier you want to go to (can get it with git log)

Comment: @FitzChill I didn't commit any work but when I do 'git pull' and then 'git checkout master' it says its up to date, even though through the latest comment on github and what is in my main cpp file on the github website, I can see that the changes I made are not there but only on my system. I need to permanently replace my files with what is remotely on github..

Comment: Does your "git status" shows up modified content ? if so doing a "git stash" will save your current files in a side workspace and remove all your local modification (go back to a clean state). If you don't need to access those modification later just make a "git checkout ." (do not forget the point) that will undo all not staged for commit work. If you have added file for commit (using "git add ") you will need to do a "git reset ." first.

Comment: @FitzChill Okay the 'git stash' and then 'git checkout .' worked, I now have my previous version showing and compiling when I open visual studio, thank you! You should make it your answer.

Comment: git stash should have been enough but I am pleased to hear that it helped you. Do not hesitate to read http://jwiegley.github.io/git-from-the-bottom-up/ it explain a lot on how git works

Answer (score 0):

First, please backup your project or latest commit somewhere (you said you don't need it but anyway my solution backups the last commit).
If you did one commit you can *stash* the last commit with:

```
git reset HEAD~1
git stash
```

After you backed up your changes, **If you don't need any local changes/commits you made and willing to reset your branch to its latest remote version (last successful push you made)**, run:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/<remote-branch-name>
git push -f
```

Note again that any local change or local commit (no push) on this branch will be lost after this `git push -f`, so make sure you check the current state of your branch after the `reset` command.